# In Razor view - how to detect browser type and version to select type of linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, razor

I am trying to create and launch a website(C# .Net MVC) for the very first time using razor views .

I have used linear-gradient heavily in the website and since launching I realize that there is no support for gradients  in IE versions 9 and lower

I would like to select gradient styles depending on browsers type and version.

For example:

```
@if(browser is IE 9 and under){
style="background: #ffffff;
}
Else{
style="background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 100px,#b8dbff 100%);
}
```

How can I detect the browser type and version in Razor view?

What’s the easiest way to filter browser versions that aren’t compatible with liner-gradients?

Hats off to front-end developers , I had no idea these cross browser issues are such a problem.

I myself use to complain a lot when something doesn’t work in a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Razor engine to serve a different view based on the caller, but it sounds like your situation can be handled with HTML/CSS.

If IE9 is your only problem, you can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) and include extra styles/stylesheet.

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
   #foo { background-color: #fff; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

But for your particular question, you should be able do something even more simple and just modify your stylesheet:

```
body{
    /* all browsers */
    background: red;

    /* newer browsers overwrite the previous value; old browsers ignore */
    background: linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red); 
}
```

IE9 doesn't know what "linear-gradient" means, and so ignores it. This is [defined behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#unsupported-values) upon which you can rely.

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/K67yd/2/show/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on Modernizr, a javascript library for detecting browser supported features. I guess it will do the job.

You might find something here: http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css

And a good video for understanding the concept: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/126-using-modernizr/